# How can I make my own jQuery dialog use opacity like the jQuery UI Dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm rolling my own jQuery dialog box.

I want my dialog box to "turn the screen dark" in the background and be "modal" like the jQuery UI dialog box.

However, I'm having trouble.  I've tried doing this two different ways, and neither produces satisfactory results.

Here's one method that doesn't work.  When I do this, my dialog appears transparent.

```
functions.OpenDialog = function (dialogId) {
    _initializeDialog(dialogId);
    var dialog = $('#' + dialogId);
    var dialogWrapper = $("[data-type='dialogWrapper'][data-dialogid='" + dialogId + "']")
    dialogWrapper.show();
    dialog.show();
};

function _initializeDialog(dialogId) {
    var dialog = $('#' + dialogId);
    dialog.wrap("<div></div>");
    var dialogWrapper = dialog.parent();
    dialogWrapper
        .attr('data-type', 'dialogWrapper')
        .attr('data-dialogid', dialogId)
        .css('position', 'fixed')
        .css('top', '0px')
        .css('left', '0px')
        .css('height', '100%')
        .css('width', '100%')
        .css('display', 'none')
        .css('background-color', 'black')
        .css('opacity', '0.8')
        .css('z-index', '1000');
    dialog.css('position', 'fixed');
    _initializedDialogIds.push(dialogId);
}
```

Here's another method.  This method works in IE, but not Firefox.  When I try to run this code in Firefox, the dialog appears behind the "mask" and I can't click anything.

```
function _appendMask() {
    var maskDivHtml = '<div id="' + _maskId + '"></div>';
    $(document.body).append(maskDivHtml);
    $('#' + _maskId).css('position', 'fixed');
    $('#' + _maskId).css('top', '0px');
    $('#' + _maskId).css('left', '0px');
    $('#' + _maskId).css('height', '100%');
    $('#' + _maskId).css('width', '100%');
    $('#' + _maskId).css('display', 'none');
    $('#' + _maskId).css('background-color', 'black');
    $('#' + _maskId).css('z-index', '0');
    _maskAppended = true;
}
functions.OpenDialog = function (dialogId) {
    if (!_maskAppended)
        _appendMask();
    $('#' + _maskId).css({ 'display': 'block', opacity: 0 });
    $('#' + _maskId).fadeTo(500, 0.8);
    if ($('#' + dialogId).css('z-index') == '0')
        $('#' + dialogId).css('z-index', '1');
    $('#' + dialogId).fadeIn(500);
    $('#' + dialogId).css('position', 'fixed');
};
```

I know I'm re-inventing the wheel, but I would really like to know how to make this work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a z-index issue. Check out my blog post on this subject: http://www.dittocode.com/a-simple-jquery-modal-box/

Comment: Following along with your example helped me get it straightened out, but I'm still not entirely certain where the error was.

Comment: The website linked to is now squatted on by companies who squat on domains.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would not use position:fixed, as it is not very browser compatible. I would also use some higher z-indexes, because you're bound to have content that you give a z-index to and you want this to appear on top.

Also, your second impelementation is much better, as it reuses the modal, which is good, because those things are actually pretty costly for lower versions of IE to make (IE sucks at transparency).

In the first, your dialog become transparent because it's parent (the modal) is transparent. You should make the modal a sibling rather than parent.